# Virtual array to be used into VLOOKUP and SUMIF formulas

Tags: vlookup, array-formulas, sumproduct

I have the following tables

[image]

In Table 1 I have some items with relative quantity values. Beneath, I have a look-up table from which I can find the rule for summing up the item's quantities into the right Container.

Currently I use additional columns, one for each Container, for helping in succeding the task.

Each cell in additional columns has the following formula (ex. E4):

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($B4,$D$12:$G$17,MATCH(E$2,$D$11:$G$11,0),0)="x",1,0)
```

Then, each Container has a Sum of Values calculated as follow (ex. E3):

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$4:$C$9,E$4:E$9)
```

The question is... Is there a way (no VBA) to obtain the same result without using additional helping columns?

I would like using something like this as formula (but it doesn't work):

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$4:$C$9,IF(VLOOKUP($B4:$B9,$D$12:$G$17,MATCH(E$2,$D$11:$G$11,0),0)="x",1,0))
```

In short, I don't know if (and if yes, how) the helping columns in the sheet I use can be calculated on the fly from excel as virtual columns directly into a cell formula.

No limitations in the use of VLOOkUP and SUMIF functions -> SUMIF, SUMIFS, INDEX, MATCH and any other combination of Excel functions is fine as long as the goal of eliminating the help columns is achieved.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

In `E3`, modified your formula and copied across right to G3 :

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$4:$C$9,IF(VLOOKUP(T(IF({1},$B4:$B9)),$D$12:$G$17,MATCH(E$2,$D$11:$G$11,0),0)="x",1,0))
```

Or,

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$4:$C$9*(VLOOKUP(T(IF({1},$B4:$B9)),$D$12:$G$17,MATCH(E$2,$D$11:$G$11,0),0)="x"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... it's just what I needed. Anyway I don't understand why I need of using the `T()` function or better why `IF({1},$B4:$B9)` return `#VALUE!` if I don't use `T()` function

Comment: I ask for it because if item-i wasn't a text but an ID progress unique number (for example) the formula didn't work

Comment: $B4:$B4 is a range, VLOOKUP does not accept range as its Lookup value, it need T(IF({1},...)) to convert the range to array reference. If it was a number, changed it to N(IF({1},...))

Comment: But, if you have Dynamic functions in Office 365, T(IF({1},...)) or N(IF({1},...)) is not required.